# Sonarqube update existing issues after modification of rules

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to update existing issues after changing a rule policy?

I am using sonar-cxx community and it seems that the rule `cppcheck:uninitMemberVar` has been changed from code smell to bug.
The problem is that it has not updated existing issues in my projects, so existing issues of that type are listed as Code smell where new issues are listed as bug.

Is there a way to update the existing issues to the new rule policy?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this manually in the "Issues" page, using the "Bulk Change" feature:

1. On the "Rules" page, you look for the `cppcheck:uninitMemberVar` rule
2. At the bottom of the page, you click on the number of issues found for that rule

   - This is the figure that is between parenthesis: `Issues (XXX)`
3. Now you are on the "Issues" page, click on the top-right "Bulk Change" button

   - In the modal window, select "Change Type" to "Bug"
   - Click "Apply"
   - Note that you might have to do this more than once because issues are processed by batch of 500 elements at a time

Comment: Thank you @Fabrice for the answer. I already did it for some of my project but wanted to know if there was an automatic way to do it. The problem is that we have to do it each time there is a rule change (hopefully this does not happen too often).